# Gracenote entourage possible issue with Android Lollipop

Tags: gracenote

I use Gracenote entourage in my App to detect the TV channel the user is watching.

It was working great until I upgraded the phone I use to debug my App to Lollipop.
Now I can never get a successful match whatever the channel I'm watching.
I got no Error Exceptions from Entourage SDK, everything seems works fine except that each time the network is queried for a match, no succesful matches are found.
I tried with another phone on Android 4.3 and entourage works fine with exactly the same code.
Does anyone has the same issue with Entourage on Android Lollipop ?
Is there a way to debug this issue by activate logs in Entourage Android SDK ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble as you, looks like it is the fact Lollipop isn't supported yet. Looks like a version is upcoming though. Source: https://twitter.com/GracenoteDev/status/571098260279922688

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Entourage Android SDK (2.2.0.3162) should support Lollipop. Please download from https://developer.gracenote.com/entourage and give it a try.